# Advanced File Reading Questions

Tags: c++, file-io

So, here is my code:

```
include <iostream>
include <fstream>
include <string>
include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int Year, VIN, Mileage;
string Model, Make, Condition;

ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("usedcars.txt");

if (!myfile)//checking to see if the txt file is begin read
{
    cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
}

while (myfile >> Year >> VIN >> Mileage >> Make >> Model >> Condition)//this is a loop so that the program keeps running 
{
    /*Test 1...just printing to see if my file came out into the program
    std::string strInput;
    getline(myfile, strInput);
    cout << strInput << endl;*/

    cout << Year << " " << VIN << " " << Mileage << " " << Make << " " << Model << " " << Condition << " " << endl;

    if (Year > 2013 && Mileage < 30000 && Condition == "excellent"){
        std::cout << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(25) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::setfill('*') << "CERTIFIED PRE-OWNED" << std::setw(25) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(25) << std::endl;
    }

    else if (Year <= 2013 && Year >= 2010 && Mileage < 50000 && Condition == "good"){
        std::cout << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(25) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::setfill('*') << "USED" << std::setw(25) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(25) << std::endl;

    }
    else{
        std::cout << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(25) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::setfill('*') << "BARGIN BASEMENT" << std::setw(25) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(25) << std::endl;
    }
}// ends while

myfile.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
```

my txt file is as follows:

2013
35802374082
48,895
subaru 
wrx
good

2009
92483752098
23,496
subaru
impreza
good

2016
29883573982
10,004
subaru
sti
excellent

2015
293485729847
33,786
subaru
legacy
excellent

2015 
2409857287029
29,876
subaru
legacy
good

2012
30857120487223
55,678
subaru
wrx
good

2010
49857298479384
49,789
subaru 
wrx
excellent

2016
02483752087045
7,999
subaru
svx
excellent

2009
39485792348755
15,000
subaru
forester
good

2008
02584708245094
60,000
subaru
frs
good

My goal is to use this code to create "car banners" using my information in my file. my program is suppose to choose what banner to make based on .txt files The program is suppose to take the string values from the .txt file, convert them to int, then use them for the if conditions to choose which one will be used. I've been staring at code all over and I'm pretty sure I confused myself.

Comment: You may have an issue with the comma, ',', in your numbers.  Use a debugger and verify that the numbers with comma are processed correctly.

Comment: You must have noticed that `cout << Year << " " << VIN << " " << Mileage << " " << Make << " " << Model << " " << Condition << " " << endl;` didn't print what you'd hoped for, yet you don't bother to show what output you are getting, and what have you tried to do to adjust your code?  Hints: some VIN's are too big for 32-bit `int`s, and numbers with commas in them can't be read directly into `int`s using the default locale settings: you could read them into `std::string`s then write some code to convert them to integers.  In general, get one thing working and tested at a time.